# Why are there no security measures to protect against drawing on other application windows via X11?

Tags: x11

I've recently been studying the X Windowing System and I've discovered that it is fairly trivial to draw on a window that was created by another process. All you need is the window ID. I'm not sure how window IDs and other existing window information is retrieved over the X11 core protocol, but it is clearly possible as there is a simple X11 utility called xwininfo which does exactly that.

xwininfo does not require root privileges, nor does one require root privileges to draw on windows created by other applications. In fact, I just painted pixels directly onto an existing terminal window without any elevated privileges from user-space.

Is this not a security issue? The fact that any application can draw on the windows of any other application seems like it could raise problems, such as undismissable advertisements drawn by malware.

What is the reason for this? It would be easy to generate, say, a shared HMAC key for each window and have the client sign each request.

My first guess is obviously performance -- if it took signing and verifying client requests in order to draw a few pixels in the window, there would probably be noticeable latency. Yet, the latency would probably still be negligible for many simple desktop applications, so why aren't there any sort of security measures in place, even optional ones? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

X11 is a protocol for allowing remote displaying of graphical user interfaces. Nowadays, usually, the X server (the one in charge of communicating with the "window manager" or "desktop environment") runs mostly on local desktops, and is run as root. Among other reasons, this means the X server has access to everything running under it and as there is no isolation between apps (it could be, mind you, it's just usually not done due to various practical reasons), you get to do whatever you want, although the client applications run as unprivileged users.

Quoting the *Integrity* section of the NSA's "[Securing the X Window System With SELinux](https://www.nsa.gov/Portals/70/images/resources/everyone/digital-media-center/publications/research-papers/securing-the-x-window-system-with-selinux-report.pdf)":

> The current X server offers little protection for the integrity of
>   client program data. The X server does not interact directly with the
>   data of the client. Clients can draw directly into another client’s
>   window and can send input,or any other type of event, directly to a
>   client. A malicious client can cause another client to present false
>   information to the user. Or an attacker could insert malicious
>   commands into the input stream of a terminal emulator. These types of
>   attacks can cause  an application to violate the system’s integrity
>   policy, and the protections presented in this paper are designed to
>   protect the integrity of X clients.

This are some of the reasons on why work was started on alternative X display systems as Mir or [Wayland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wayland_(display_server_protocol)). The latter being the one to where most of the Linux desktops are heading.

If you want to know more about the security of the X Window System, the paper above from NSA is a great resource.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Some history: X11 was developed in the 80s. One of the goals was to allow multiple programs to work co-cooperatively on a single display. At that point of time, there was little/no hacking, remote access, etc. Also, remember that at that time there was no openssl, and most connection was using clear-text (ftp, telnet). Security concern and functionality (ssh) came much later.

Getting to the point that the system was working and stable was a major achievement. In retrospect, this would have been a good idea to extend the design to support protection between clients.